# Return row position - Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

I return a table with position:

```
select * 
from (
    select *, row_number() over() as position 
    from organization
) result 
where data1 = 'Hello';
```

Gives back this, which is correct:

```
data1 | Hello
data2 | Joe
position | 5
```

But when I do:

```
select position 
from (
   select *, row_number() over() as position 
   from organization
) result 
where data1 = 'Hello';
```

It returns:

```
position | 25
```

What am missing here?
How can I modify this query to return 5?

Comment: You should include sorting within the window function with an `ORDER BY` clause. Without it the result is arbitrary.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A table in RDBMS is an unordered set of rows. Without an `order by` clause in the `row_number`, it will assign row numbers arbitrarily.

Use proper `order by` clause to get consistent results:

```
select position 
from (
   select *,
        row_number() over(
           order by ??   -- add column(s) here
        ) as position 
   from organization
) result 
where data1 = 'Hello';
```

Comment: Thanks, I want the ordering to be the same as in the table "organization" right now, the reason is that other application lists records one by one from top to bottom as it is now. Which "order by" can I use in this case?

Comment: @AntonKim: there is no such thing as "the order in the table".

Comment: @AntonKim - A table in RDBMS is an unordered set of rows. There is no such thing as table order. You need to define which column you want to order by.

Comment: @GurV ok thanks, is there any other option since the app just lists records from `select * from.....`  without `order by` to mimic that?

Comment: @AntonKim - If you have an autoincrementing ID column in your table you can order on that.

Comment: @AntonKim: the **only** way (_really_: the only) to get a defined sort order is to use `order by`. There is **no** alternative.