# How to get the position of a record

Tags: postgresql, next.js, prisma

This might be a dumb and simple question, but since I am a completely newbie I could not find a workaround.

Lets say I have these users in the DB :

Me with maxScore : 4
John with maxScore: 3
Doe with maxScore: 9
Ana with maxScore: 12
Bob with maxScore: 1

I would like to get "3" as a result since after ordering the users, "Me" is the third one with 4 maxScore. BUT if the app has lets say 2000 users, I want to get the ranking of "Me", for example 1375.

How can I achieve this?

thanks in advance

I have been able to sort my DB with

```
  const usersAround = await prisma.user.findMany({
    orderBy: {
      maxScore: "desc",
    },
    cursor: {
      id: myUser.id,
    },
    take: 5,
  });
```

But I want to get the index (or the rank) of my user in the ranking of the scores.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Raw Query](https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-client/raw-database-access) to pass a SQL query to find your global position.

This Stack Overflow [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43053297/4154062) provides the sql query, which you can pass in the $queryRaw function to get the position.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```js
const users = await prisma.user.findMany({
  orderBy: {
    maxScore: "desc",
  },
  take: 5,
});

const ranking = users.findIndex(user => user.id === myUser.id) + 1
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer, but that does not solve my problem. Sorry because I now realise i was not clear enough. That was only an example. I need to get the global Index, not only of the found items. Just like some standings. If the user is in the 600th place then I want the number 600 even tho in my query I use "take:5"